# Java send gmail

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I'm dealing with problem sending gmail's from my app, i have following code:

```
public class Notificator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("r","");
                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@no-spam.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("to@no-spam.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," +
                "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

And im getting following error :     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect

Threfore I enabled access for less secured devices and also enabled intellij in firewall.

edit: Yes i have correct credintials, just erased them before putting here.

Comment: So your authentication was wrong. Do you really have a blank password? And a one-letter username ?

Comment: No, I just covered mine actual details. I have correct ones and still failed to connect.

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has [tips for debugging connection problems](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).

Comment: @BillShannon already tried with no luck.

Comment: What exactly did you try and what exactly were the results?  What does the JavaMail debug output show?

Comment: Did you try the same SMTP settings with an existing email client such as Thunderbird?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/dw0N0Czu

Comment: @MikhailRamendik yes i did. And still error with failed to connect. Even do i tried to only copy existing codes, which shoud be working

Comment: If the existing email client gives you an error too, your Java code is not at fault. You have a problem with gmail. Try the gmail support forum https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/gmail ; describe the issue as it happens with the existing mail client.

Comment: @MikhailRamendik actually my current client works, while code doesn't I don't really understand why, but I have contacted google about this issue, thank you for providing me link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the gmail account details (email address and password) or you will always receive an Authorisation error.

Here's a sample which i have used previously:

```
    public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        javaMailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        javaMailSender.setPort(587);
        javaMailSender.setUsername("youremailaddress@gmail.com");
        javaMailSender.setPassword("GMAIL PASSWORD HERE");

        javaMailSender.setJavaMailProperties(getMailProperties());
        return javaMailSender;
    }

    private Properties getMailProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp"));
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.debug", "false");
        return properties;
    }

    JavaMailSender javaMailSender = getJavaMailSender();

    private void sendEmail(){
        javaMailSender.send((MimeMessage mimeMessage) -> {
            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
            message.setFrom("from@no-spam.com");
            message.setTo("to@no-spam.com");
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," +
                "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");
        });
    }
```

Comment: I have specified those, but i just erased them in order not to reveal my credintials.

Comment: Try setting the STARTTLS property to true and using port 587. Gmail has exposes port 587 for SMTP with STARTTLS

Comment: Tried, still no luck with connection.

Answer (score 1):

Check the correct properties:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true";
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```